# Using Meteor with Iron-router to improve crawling with Google AJAX specifications

Tags: meteor, web-crawler, iron-router

I have a Meteor site with [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).  When I use Google's webmaster tools and "fetch as Google", it comes up with an empty body.

Reading Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) on how to make the application crawlable, I believe I need to add a `meta` tag and return a plain html version of the page if the GET parameter `?_escaped_fragment=` is sent.

Is there a simple way to do this with Iron-Router?  I have tried diverting the browser to a different template if the GET parameter is present, eg:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'home',
        onBeforeAction: function () {
            if (this.params['_escaped_fragment']=='') {
                this.route.options.template = 'another_page';
            }
        },
    });
});
```

However, this just substitutes another template using javascript, which Google won't see either.  Is there a way to provide a plain html file if a specific GET parameter is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `spiderable` package to your project:

```
meteor add spiderable
```

This will automatically add the correct `<meta>` tag to your page, and spiders will be served a PhantomJS-generated version of your site.

Note that the Google Webmaster tools will still show the empty AJAX version of your page in the crawl results, but Google will crawl and index your page correctly. This appears to be a bug in the Webmaster tools. You can verify that the app was successfully crawled by going to your Webmaster tools homepage (where the list of your websites is). Your website should have a screenshot showing what the Google crawler actually saw.

Comment: Hello, I am following the discover meteor book. I have successfully installed the Spiderable Package. When I call http://******:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=. I get the first 5 posts returned as html even with js disabled. But passing parameters seams NOT to work. eg: 
http://*****:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=/new/10 will just return either the first 5 posts. Is the spiderable package not compatible with the iron-router?

Comment: Spiderable worked for me for a while, although there were SSL issues and other problems getting phantomJS to work with my host. Recently I switched to prerender.io and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo:

> if (this.params['_escaped_fragment']=='') {

should be

> if (this.params['_escaped_fragment_']=='') {

[You missed an underscore.](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=_escaped_fragment&oq=_escaped_fragment&aqs=chrome..69i57.752j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)